# How to only get data of first row of all table on a Wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape data from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains**) Wikipedia page.

Here below is the code that I'm currently using.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_hip_hop_music")
albumdatasaved = ""
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    albumdata = ""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        albumdata = albumdata + "," + data.text
    albumdatasaved = albumdatasaved + "\n" + albumdata[1:]

print(albumdatasaved)
```

I need only first row data of every table like below image. How I can do that?

[image: table]

Comment: Wikipedia has an API, you don't need to scrape data.

Comment: Peter Wood can you tell me how i can get that data

Comment: I have no idea. I would read the documentation. https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia

Comment: You might also be interested in the DBPedia project and API: https://wiki.dbpedia.org/about, https://wiki.dbpedia.org/rest-api.

Comment: Also the wikipedia api documentation itself: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

Comment: image shows column, not row - so you need first row or first column? To get only first element you could try `find()` instead of `findAll()` or `findAll()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fully working code for your problem, using API is better way but I understand that you need a quick solution for it...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains")

albumdatasaved = ""
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        if data.text.strip() and data.text[0] == ".":
            albumdatasaved += data.text.strip() + "\n"
            break

print(albumdatasaved)
```

Comment: thnaks bro you are awesome